# crossproduct matrix unexpectedly full of NAs

Tags: r, matrix

So I took some information from a CSV, stored it as a matrix, and tried to compute the following operations on the result, but it gave me a 2x2 array of NA.  Not seeing the problem here.

```
data <- read.csv('qog.csv', sep=';')
X <- matrix( log( data$wdi_gnipc ) )
X <- cbind(X, data$ciri_empinx_new)
t(X) %*% X
```

When I look at X and t(X) they look like how I expect them to, so I am matrix-multiplying a 2xn matrix with an nx2 matrix (n is some large number like 193) and so the matrix product should be well-defined and give a meaningful 2x2 answer.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Note:  When I try

a <- rbind(c(1,2), c(3,4))
t(a) %*% a

it gives the desired result.  Not sure what the important difference is between that and what I'm doing with the data.

Comment: Any NA in your data? Try `sum(is.na(X))`.

Comment: Ah, I really didn't think there would be, but you're right, there is.

Comment: @flodel Wait, when I do `sum(is.na(X))` it prints 7.  But when I enter `sum(is.na(X[,1]))` it prints 0 and I get the same when I enter `sum(is.na(X[,2]))`.  These are the only two columns, so ... any idea WTF?

Comment: And a manual scan of the data shows no NA values.

Comment: ... Sorry, never mind, just realized that I had previously run a command to remove NAs and thought I was starting back from scratch when I wasn't.  I found the NAs and all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's make that an answer. For the cross product to be filled with `NA`, you must have at least one `NA` per column inside `X`. You can find the number of `NA`s per column by running:

```
colSums(is.na(X))
```

and by all likelihood you will have that

```
all(colSums(is.na(X)) > 0)
# [1] TRUE
```